# convert string to Default date Format

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting, jquery-globalize

Hi I have use the string object for represent the date in the following format

```
var date="18/01/2011";
var dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy";
```

**Note:**

In my scenorio i have use the dd/MM/yyyy format;

dateFormat will be different in my client side.

how to convert these date default JavaScript dateFormat as MM/dd/yyyy in Generic way.

I have tried in by split date by and swap the month ,date to achieve this requirement. But in my client side i dont know about the format of the date how to convert any other format to default Javascript format

Comment: Is your question how to figure out what the client browser's date field order is? E.g., to know whether the user's locale uses `mm/dd/yyyy` (U.S. format) or `dd/mm/yyyy` (UK and many others) or...?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
var date="18/01/2011";
var parts = date.split('/');
var result = new Date(parts[2], parts[1], parts[0]);
```

Comment: I don't think that's the question. In any case, the proper way to flag a duplicate is to vote to close as a duplicate (if you have the rep) or to *comment* on the question linking to the duplicate (if you don't).

Answer (score -1):

var datestring = "2014-02-27:04:05";var d = Date(datestring);